# How to put the function into a module in magento?

Tags: magento

I am sorry i am a newbie of magento. now, the following code which can get rand product on the same category. when put the code in **view.phtml**.

```
<!--for show other product-->
<?php $categories = $_product->getCategoryIds(); ?>
    <?php
        $result = array();
        foreach($categories as $cat_id) {
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
            $category->load($cat_id);
            $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
            foreach ($collection as $product) {
                $result[] = $product->getId();
            }
 
        }
    ?>
    <div class="box-others-also-like">
        <ul>
        <?php
        if(sizeof($result) >= 5)
        {
           $ourneed = array_rand($result,5);
           foreach($ourneed as $cc)
            {
             $thisproduct= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($result[$cc]);
             ?>
             <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $thisproduct->getProductUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $thisproduct->getName(); ?>" ><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($thisproduct, 'small_image')->resize(200) ?>" width="200" height="200" alt="<?php echo $thisproduct->getName(); ?>" /></a>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php
        }else
        {
           foreach($result as $cc)
            {
             $thisproduct= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($cc);
             ?>
 
                <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $thisproduct->getProductUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $thisproduct->getName(); ?>" ><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($thisproduct, 'small_image')->resize(200) ?>" width="200" height="200" alt="<?php echo $thisproduct->getName(); ?>" /></a>
                </li>
            <?php
            }
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--for show other product-->
```

now, i want to put the function in a module, How do i do?  supposed i have created the skeleton of the module.the module name is **Rand**. the packagename is **Web**.

which file should i write the above code in?`Block` or `Model` or `Helper` or `controllers`

many thanks.

Comment: May I suggest starting with Alan Storm's articles? http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#magento_for_php_developers

Answer (score 0):

In Magento, to call a function we should define that function in Block. It is the better way. We can call that function by using $this.

```
$this->functionName()
```

But we can define that function in helper also, for that we need to call that function like below.

```
Mage::helper('yourmodule/yourclassfile')->prtHelloWorld();
```

Calling a model function will affect the MVC pattern. So don't try this.